# C++: static analysis for const?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

I know there are a bunch of static analysis tools available for c++. However when googling I could not find one that seems to be able to warn about values and functions that could have been marked as `const` but aren't.

So in particular if I have a function like this:

```
int add(int a, const int b) {
    int result = a + b;
    return result;
}
```

I want the tool to warn me (or issue an error) about the variables `a` and `result` which could have been marked as `const` but weren't.
Furthermore if `add` had been a member function I would also want to be warned about it not being declared as `const.

So for one I want a tool that helps me enforcing const-correctness and if possible it should go beyond that and should make me use `const` in every single situation that my code currently allows for.

Are there tools that can do this for c++? Or is this even a compiler option in e.g. `clang` that I can't seem to find?

I was thinking that maybe this would be something that could be done with `clang-tidy` somehow if there is not a tool available already...

Comment: For those thinking about voting to close this question due to it asking for a specific tool/library: Note that I'm not asking for "the best" here. I just want to know whether a tool with such capabilities exists. Thus this question does have a clear answer.

Comment: What would you do with a "yes" or "no" as answer?

Comment: Yes there are such tools. Asking for which tools is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I think you can configure CLion to do this.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt fair enough. I'm not looking for a yes/no answer. But I wanted to express that there is no room for subjective discussions here. either a tool does have these capabilities or it does not. Therefore I think it is pretty similar to questions that ask "How can I do X in c++" which might have multiple answers as well but are still not closed as OT on this site

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well in a sense this question deals with "a specific programming topic". Namely "How can I make sure that I use const everywhere it applies?"

Comment: I would guess you could write a clang-tidy check to do this.

Comment: Seems clang-tidy can already do part of that: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-make-member-function-const.html

Answer (score 1):

[Resharper-C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/) for VisualStudio does warn about that (it's not free). I am not sure what they use behind the scenes. It could just be clang-tidy.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not clang-tidy. It's a proprietary inspection of Resharper. More info at: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Inspections_CPP.html#BestPractice